# Javascript If condition with different variables and associated ids

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I created an if condition, but I want to check on multiple variables. The variable belong to a different id, as you can see below.

Is it possible to optimize the code, because i don't want to copy-past and change the variables.

```
if (T11 > 33){
    document.getElementById("T11").innerHTML = '-';
}
else if(T11 > 2){
    document.getElementById("T11").innerHTML = T11-30;
    document.getElementById("T11").style.textDecoration = 'underline';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("T11").innerHTML = T11;
    }



if (T12 > 33){
        document.getElementById("T12").innerHTML = '-';
    }
    else if(T12 > 2){
        document.getElementById("T12").innerHTML = T12-30;
        document.getElementById("T12").style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("T12").innerHTML = T12;
        }



if (T.. > 33){
        document.getElementById("T..").innerHTML = '-';
    }
    else if(T.. > 2){
        document.getElementById("T..").innerHTML = T..-30;
        document.getElementById("T..").style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("T..").innerHTML = T..;
        }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: `if` doesn't create a loop ... Note also, that dash (`-`)  is not a valid character in a JS identifier.

Comment: **if-loop**... What ?

Comment: `if` is not a loop.  But it sounds like what you want *is* a loop.  Loops are a *very* common control structure in programming, you should take a look and practice some with JavaScript tutorials.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: please add the rest, where `T11` gets it value.

Comment: `T1` through `T33` should be `t`, where `t` is an **array**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T1` through `T33` should be `t`, where `t` is an **array**. Then a single loop gets this done. If `T1` through `T33` **can't** be made an array (but I can't imagine why they couldn't), you can create a temporary array of them first:

```
var t = [T1, T2, T3, T4, ... ];
```

But again, really, you shouldn't have `T1` through `T33` at all; just `t`.

Once you have `t`, you could use `forEach`:

```
t.forEach(function(val, index) {
   var element = document.getElementById("T" + (index + 1));
   if (val > 33){
        element.innerHTML = '-';
    }
    else if (t[n] > 2){
        element.innerHTML = val - 30;
        element.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
    else {
        element.innerHTML = val;
    }
});
```

...but if you want a `for` loop:

```
for (var n = 0; n < t.length; ++n) {
   var val = t[n];
   var element = document.getElementById("T" + (n + 1));
   if (val > 33){
        element.innerHTML = '-';
    }
    else if (t[n] > 2){
        element.innerHTML = val - 30;
        element.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
    else {
        element.innerHTML = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your data inside an array of objects

```
const data = [{
   variable: T11,
   name: "T11" 
},{
    variable: T12,
    name: "T12"
}];

data.forEach(d => {
    let element = document.getElementById(d.name);
    if(d.variable > 33){
        element.innerHTML = '-';
    }else if(d.variable > 2){
        element.innerHTML = d.variable - 30;
        element.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }else{
        element.innerHTML = d.variable
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make it a function

```
codeReduce(13,TD1) //call like this

function codeReduce(id,name){
    if(id > 33){
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = '-';
    }
    else if(id > 2){
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = id-30;
        document.getElementById(name).style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object, where you have a string as key and a value, like

```
values = {
    T11: 20,
    T22: 10
}
```

Then use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and loop

```
Object.keys(values).forEach(function (k) {
    var element = document.getElementById(k);
    if (values[k] > 33) {
        element.innerHTML = '-';
        return;
    }
    element.innerHTML = values[k];
    if (values[k] > 2) {
        element.innerHTML -= 30;
        element.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
});
```